# Excel VBA Userform Listbox Dynamic Context Menu Using .OnAction Method

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, contextmenu, userform

I have built a dynamic context menu for a `Userform` `Listbox`.

Within this `Listbox` are a series files. My aim is that when you right click on a file, a context menu pops up with a list of folder locations. Left clicking on one of these folder locations copies the file to that location.

*I will be using the* `.CopyFile(Location, Destination, [Overwrite])` *method to do this.*

I'm having difficulty dynamically assigning `.OnAction` events for each `Item` added.

`Userform` Module Code

```
Option Explicit
Private Const mCONTEXT_MENU_NAME = "myRightClickListbox"
Private m_clsContextMenu As CContextMenu

'Function mySendTo(fName As String)
    'MsgBox fName
'End Function

Sub mySendTo(fName As String)
    MsgBox fName
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
Dim myString As String: myString = "C:\myFolder\"
Dim FolderName As String: FolderName = Dir("C:\myFolder\", vbDirectory)    

If Button = 2 Then
        '*\\Listbox right click context menu
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.CommandBars(mCONTEXT_MENU_NAME).Delete 'remove any previous instance
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set m_clsContextMenu = New CContextMenu

        With CommandBars.Add(mCONTEXT_MENU_NAME, Position:=msoBarPopup)
            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, before:=1, temporary:=True)
                .Caption = "Send to"

                i = 0
                Do While FolderName <> ""
                    If FolderName <> "." And FolderName <> ".." Then
                        If (GetAttr(myString & FolderName) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                            i = i + 1
                            With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=i, temporary:=True)
                                .FaceId = 23
                                .Caption = FolderName
                                .Tag = "t" & FolderName
                                .OnAction = "'mySendTo " & FolderName & "'"
                                '.OnAction = "=mySendTo(" & FolderName & ")"
                                '.Parameter = FolderName
                            End With
                        End If
                    End If
                    FolderName = Dir()
                Loop
            End With

            Set m_clsContextMenu.LBox = Me.ListBox1
        End With
        '*//
    End If
End Sub
```

`Class` Module Code `CContextMenu`

```
Public LBox As MSForms.ListBox
```

The code above successfully creates a right click activated context menu for a `Userform` `Listbox` which consists of a sub-menu `Type:=msoControlPopup` containing `Items` for each folder within the specified `FolderName` directory.

I am trying to dynamically assign `.OnAction` events for each `Item` created to call the `mySendTo` `Sub` or `Function`. I've been told that you may only call `Functions` by name in this manner and that calling a `Sub` with it's own parameters will fail. None the less I have tried both and neither seem to work. Although both trigger an `Error: 400` which means Excel is trying to call the event.

Both events just trigger a `MsgBox` displaying the parameter `String` (I have done this for simplicity until I know the code runs correctly).

What **is** important is that when each `Item` in the sub-menu is clicked, it triggers code that references that specific `Item.Caption` text - in this case, the sub-folder name within the `FolderName` directory (the location of itself).

I intend to copy files from the `Listbox` to the new destination folder indicated by that of the context sub-menu `Item`.

I know that I'm close with my `.OnAction` syntax but whether it's because I'm mis-using my `Sub` / `Function` with parameter call events, or because I'm also trying to dynamically assign the `.OnAction` event to an already dynamically created context sub-menu `Item`, I just can't for the life of me figure it out.

If you paste the above code into a blank `Userform` module and add a `Listbox` named "ListBox1", you should have a working right click activated context menu with a sub-menu.

If you try and click one of these `Items` you should also receive the `Error: 400`.

Any help on how I can pass a dynamic `Sub` or `Function` to each `Item` with a parameter being it's own `.Caption` will be **much** appreciated, and once again thank you for your time.

Mr. J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all your OnAction to a public Sub with no parameters.  Then inside that Sub, use Application.CommandBars.ActionControl to get the specific command bar item that triggered the event.  Then you can get a property of the command bar item that identifies which item you are dealing with. The .Parameter property is the best choice.

In your case you could just use the Caption property I suppose... but that's dangerous because you might later decide to format it, or truncate it, or whatever.  Thus make sure set the command item's Parameter field to be the folder in question (which you have in your code already - but commented out).

So in your original code:

```
With .Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, before:=i, temporary:=True)
  .Caption = FolderName
  'etc etc
  .OnAction = "'MyWorkbookName.xlsx'!mySendTo"
  .Parameter = FolderName
End With
```

By the way, always specify the fully qualified macro name in .OnAction.  I've learned this through hard experience.  Make sure to always put the workbook name in single quotes like I have it above.  (The quotes aren't always needed, but often are... and it doesn't hurt to always have it.)

Then in your event handler:

```
Public Sub mySend()
  Dim sourceFolder as String

  On Error resume Next
  sourceFolder = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter
  On Error goto 0

  if sourceFolder <> "" Then GoOnAndDoWhatever(sourceFolder)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Unfortunately the `.OnAction` line still triggers `Error: 400`. If I comment block this line, there is no error (but also no event). Also, If I use a breakpoint at the start of my `Public Sub mySendTo()` - nothing triggers. I noticed you used `MyWorkbookName.xlsx` as your example, but my file is an AddOn file `.xlam` - does this matter? Either way, the `.OnAction` isn't triggering the event. Any thoughts?..

Comment: You get an Error 400 when you assign the OnAction on when you click the command bar item that should trigger the OnAction?

Comment: Hey does your .xlam have a custom ribbon in it?

Comment: Yes to the Error 400, No to the custom ribbon. The Error 400 appears after every second click e.g. First right click (context menu opens), left click on item (nothing happens). Second right click (context menu opens), left click on item (Error 400). And repeat, first (nothing), second (error), etc.

Comment: Is this code (the button event handler) in the same file (the .xlam) as the mySend routine?

Comment: Yes all code is located within the same .xlam file. More specifically, both the button event handler and the mySendTo routine are located within the same Userform code module.

Comment: Try putting mySend in a public module (not in a user form).

Comment: That worked! I feel so ashamed... I made one small change to your event handler code: `sourceFolder = Application.CommandBars.ActionControl.Parameter` you don't need to use the `Set` prefix here as it's only a `String` and doesn't require any special declarations. Thanks for all your help, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Very happy to help!  I've pull my hair out a million times on things like this...